# Clean way to get around * operator in tensor indexing

Tags: indexing, torch

Hi I was wondering if there was a clean way to get around the * operator indexing issue in Python 3.10. For example I would like to do something like, although the [*] indexing operation is not allowed in Colab.

```
t = torch.zeros(5, 6, 8)
index = [3, 2, 7]
print(t[*index])
```

Obviously there are ways to hard code this if the number of dimensions is known, but in my case the number of dimensions varies and can conceivably go up to 8-10.

Comment: I'm not familiar with torch, but if its indexing works like numpy, you just need to use a tuple instead of a list for `index` in order for `t[index]` to work.

Comment: Ok it works with a tuple but not a list or anything else. It seems like a dumb question now but the reason why I thought it wouldn't work is that if the index is of a list type then it will treat it as if the entire array refers only to the first index. For example, t[[3, 2, 7]] or t[torch.tensor([3, 2, 7])] will error because it cannot access index 7 on the first dimension so I assumed a list or tuple would behave the same, but t[(3, 2, 7)] does what I need. Makes sense because tuple is the closest approximation of *iterable. Thanks a lot!